# How can htmx use hx-* attributes? Is that legal HTML?

Tags: html, htmx

htmx uses attributes such as hx-post, but those are obviously not standard attributes. But as far as I understand, only [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) are allowed for custom attributes. **So how can htmx use hx-foo attributes?** Is htmx doing something non-standard that just happens to work? Am I missing something about custom attributes? For example, is there a way to register custom attributes from JS?

Comment: The default behavior of browsers is to ignore tags and attributes they don't understand. This is by design. Also notice the [HTMLX docs](https://htmx.org/docs/) say *"if you prefer, you can use the data- prefix when using htmx"* in case your validator complains.